# 'npm run build' failed in AWS CodeBuild but succeeded locally

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I have a ReactJS application deployed to AWS using CodePipline and CodeBuild. However, in the AWS CodeBuild stage the 'npm run build' always failed with error:

```
> next build
info  - Loaded env from /app/.env.production
info  - Loaded env from /app/.env
info  - Using webpack 5. Reason: Enabled by default https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5
Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
https://nextjs.org/telemetry

info  - Checking validity of types...
Failed to compile.

./pages/_app.tsx:28:12
Type error: 'SnackbarProvider' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its instance type 'SnackbarProvider' is not a valid JSX element.
    The types returned by 'render()' are incompatible between these types.
      Type 'React.ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'import("/app/node_modules/@types/styled-jsx/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactNode'.

  26 |       <ThemeProvider theme={getTheme()}>
  27 |         <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
> 28 |           <SnackbarProvider maxSnack={5}>
     |            ^
  29 |             <Component {...pageProps} />
  30 |           </SnackbarProvider>
  31 |         </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! pos-application-process@0.1.0 build: `next build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the pos-application-process@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-04-08T06_42_37_976Z-debug.log
The command '/bin/sh -c npm run build' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

However, on my local PC, when I run 'npm run build', the build is successful. I have tried deleted node_modules folder and package-lock.json and run 'npm install' & 'npm run build'. All builds were successful. I just couldn't duplicate the error locally. Here is my package.json dependency:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@date-io/date-fns": "1.3.13",
    "@material-ui/core": "4.12.3",
    "@material-ui/data-grid": "4.0.0-alpha.37",
    "@material-ui/icons": "4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/lab": "4.0.0-alpha.60",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "3.3.10",
    "@material-ui/styles": "4.11.4",
    "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "1.6.0",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "1.20.3",
    "amazon-cognito-identity-js": "5.0.4",
    "autosuggest-highlight": "3.2.0",
    "axios": "0.21.4",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "1.13.2",
    "clsx": "1.1.1",
    "date-fns": "2.28.0",
    "global": "4.4.0",
    "html-pdf": "3.0.1",
    "html2canvas-objectfit-fix": "1.2.0",
    "jose": "4.6.0",
    "jspdf": "2.4.0",
    "mobx": "6.3.2",
    "mobx-react-lite": "3.2.0",
    "mobx-state-tree": "5.0.2",
    "next": "11.1.0",
    "notistack": "1.0.10",
    "nrm": "1.2.1",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-google-autocomplete": "2.6.1",
    "react-input-mask": "2.0.4",
    "react-number-format": "4.7.3",
    "react-pdf": "5.4.1",
    "react-use": "17.3.1",
    "react-verification-code-input": "1.2.9",
    "types-registry": "0.1.553",
    "uac-client": "0.1.11",
    "validate.js": "0.13.1",
    "yrm": "1.0.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@next/eslint-plugin-next": "12.1.0",
    "@types/react": "17.0.15",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.29.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.29.0",
    "eslint": "7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "11.0.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.24.0",
    "prettier": "2.3.2",
    "typescript": "4.3.5"
  }
```

Does anyone encounter this issue before? I really appreciate any help!

Comment: Please do the following: delete node_modules AND package-lock.json on your local machine and try installing everything again. Probably you will receive the same issue locally. The reason for this could be, that you have installed any dependency globally/locally without added it to your package.json. In the past, I often could reproduce those issues by deleting and complete reinstall the dependencies to see, what's going on. The package-lock.json should be also committed (of not already done, to be sure to install the same package versions)

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem similar this recently, but with Next.js

The Error that I was getting was:

```
COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR: Error while executing command: npm run build. Reason: exit status 1
```

I feel like your question isn't easy to answer without more info on your deployment itself. But what helped me was changing the dev-dependencies to normal dependencies in the package.json file. The Build worked after that.

Answer (score 0):

Just overriding the types manually worked for me:

Change this:

```
<ThemeProvider theme={getTheme()}>
  <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
    <SnackbarProvider maxSnack={5}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </SnackbarProvider>
  </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
  ...
```

With this:

```
{/* Otherwise SnackbarProvider doesn't build with correct type */}
<ThemeProvider theme={getTheme()}>
  <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
    {React.createElement(SnackbarProvider as React.ElementType, { maxSnack: 5 },
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    )}
  </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Few facts for you to work on as below.

1. You can verify the node version, npm version in your local vs the versions in AWS.
2. Make sure to confirm that the code builds under the versions that it should build and the versions are same in local and AWS.
   E.g.
3. Carefully go through the script of your build pipeline and look for commands included to build the code.